# Failed to bring up Etcd Plane: etcd cluster is unhealthy: hosts - in Rancher after second cluster is created

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, rancher

I create a docker image of rancher and when I deploy it in a VM server in gcloud, i can run it perfectly. I always I'm able to create one cluster. Then after that I edit the cluster config in .kube/config, and set the cluster config yaml.
The thing is that when I want to create a new cluster after the first one becomes active, the second one throws the error "Failed to bring up Etcd Plane: etcd cluster is unhealthy: hosts"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIzBO.png

I already tried downloading other rancher versions, delete the .kube/config file, and also tried to unset clusters with

```
kubectl config unset clusters
```

But nothing works. The only thing that makes it posible to get a new cluster running is to delete everithing or create a new VM.

the file ./kube/config is something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: "local"
  cluster:
    server: "https://xxxxxxx/k8s/clusters/local"
    certificate-authority-data: "xxxxxxx"

users:
- name: "local"
  user:
    token: "xxxxxx"


contexts:
- name: "local"
  context:
    user: "local"
    cluster: "local"

current-context: "local"
```

In addition to that, if I clean the storage as suggested in question 24189 of github, i erase all clusters data and then I can create a cluster again... But this erase my other clusters and i have to deploy again. Links:
Question
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/24189

```
     sh file to execute clean:
     https://github.com/rancherlabs/support- 
     tools/blob/master/extended-rancher-2-cleanup/extended- 
     cleanup-rancher2.sh
```

Should I do something with kube configuration? Should I edit something in my local VM config?

Any idea?

I expect to have two three or more clusters running in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

After months... I discovered that my aproach was wrong. Kubernetes is a technology that makes it possible to create machines as nodes. So the problem was mathematical and logical.

**I was triying to create multiple machines on a VM. Thats clearly imposible. If you want to create multiple clusters (of multple nodes) or simply a single cluster (with multiple nodes), yo've got to have a cloud administrator such as GKE, AWS, or Vsphere.** Once you have that, there you can connect a VM with rancher, and make a deploy of multiple machines in the cloud.

Your Rancher instance in form of docker image, will connect with the cloud admin, an will create the machines in the cloud.

On the other hand, **it is possible to create single node clusters in a VM but after that if you want another, it is not going to be possible.**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

[https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/09/14/how-to-create-a-single-node-kubernetes-cluster/#:~:text=minikube%20is%20the%20most%20popular,run%20outside%20the%20Linux%20environment](https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/09/14/how-to-create-a-single-node-kubernetes-cluster/#:%7E:text=minikube%20is%20the%20most%20popular,run%20outside%20the%20Linux%20environment).